# Dynamically create dropdownlist on click button in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP for 1 month.I wants to dynamically create dropdownlist whenever user click "Add" button in JSP. But, after searching for hours in the internet, there are no such articles. Previously I had tried to do the same thing (but with textbox in C#) and it works. Is it possible to dynamically create dropdownlist in JSP too?  Or I have to send to servlet to create another dropdownlist?

```
<form> 

<select> 
<option> 1 </option> 
<option> 2 </option> 
<option> 3 </option> 
</select>

<input type="Add" name="Add">

<form>
```

Comment: Did you want to create a copy of existing dropdown list or completely new dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use javascript to add element to select item or you can submit form and render new list with element you added after reload